Tor and Firebase
I’ve recently started using Tor because I live in the HK/Macau/China region (not chinese tho) and an AI chat app that I use got georestricted. I’ve been trying to get to it using VPN and Tor which worked recently until they started using Firebase.
I use MacOS. I am using NordVPN (obsfucated vpn doesn’t work, P2P doesn’t work, onion over vpn worked for two seconds and then got blocked).
I tried using Tor but it gets the firebase authorization error.
Is there any way to get around it? I’ve been told that maybe using proxychains or a proxy to change Tor’s exit node would help but how would that work and are there any step by step guides for it since I have no experience in IT?
Thank you.

what happens / stopped working exactly? Can you please describe it step by step? It will help me to answer your question

Well, the AI itself has different responses depending on censored or not. The VPN lets see the website but when I log in it is the censored version. Onion over VPN gets an error with the website (timeout error etc). It won’t let me click or type or post. For Tor, I run into captchas and then get a Firebase: error (auth/network-request-failed). And also I cannot have anything google related open otherwise I get blocked almost immediately or cannot log in. Thank you for helping.

You case is that you have identifying tokens in the account you're authorizing with on the AI website. So - wherever from you will do the login - not the query source, but the account is what sets the rules for AI. You need not just Tor or VPN from another place where the censorship rules you're struggling with are not applied - you need a different verified account from the place free from these censorship rules.

Oh okay, thank you very much.
